# Grabbing and splitting specific lines with one or more instances

Tags: bash, awk

Given a .txt file (DNA-sequence alignment report), in this format:

```
5463784 reads; of these:
  5463784 (100.00%) were paired; of these:
    841569 (15.40%) aligned concordantly 0 times
    4469608 (81.80%) aligned concordantly exactly 1 time
    152607 (2.79%) aligned concordantly >1 times
    ----
    841569 pairs aligned 0 times concordantly or discordantly; of these:
      1683138 mates make up the pairs; of these:
        1407028 (83.60%) aligned 0 times
        226521 (13.46%) aligned exactly 1 time
        49589 (2.95%) aligned >1 times
87.12% overall alignment rate
```

What is the easiest and shortest way to grab subportions of specific lines? For example if I wanted to grab the 'exactly' lines I can use:

```
awk '/exactly/{print}'
```

Which would return:

```
4469608 (81.80%) aligned concordantly exactly 1 time
226521 (13.46%) aligned exactly 1 time
```

But i'm not sure how to then split what's returned to obtain `4469608` and `226521` within an array (to then eventually sum together) to give a variable set to `4696129`.

Comment: `awk '/exactly/{print $1}'` would print the first field. You could then sum them for example sike this: `awk '/exactly/{sum+=$1} END{print sum}'`

Comment: Interesting. So no delimiter has to be specified?

Comment: Default delimiter is already set to handle space. You could change that with for example `-F=";"` on the command line or with `FS=";"` in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/exactly/ {sum=sum+$1;}END{print sum}' dna
```

Take actions on those line where exactly is present, store the value of first column in a `awk` variable called sum and in the end print.